# It's possible in rails. Before all request can i set default params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request

I want to set one parameter for all HTML requests. That parameter has a default for all links. So, how can I achieve this thing? And I also tried before-action and action middleware.

Comment: Can you give an example of why you want this? How are you using it? If it is going to be in every request why not make it a constant?

Comment: Thanks for your response Beartech,  I'm using it in my Shopify app. Because I facing some issues finding the shop domain. Because right now I'm updating my app rails 6 to 7. So that's why I want to pass shop for all requests. But I found a solution. Rails provide default_url_options method So, you can define this method in the application controller and you can set params it will set for all request.